# Docker: Insert certificate into ketstore

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, openshift, dockerfile

I'm trying to add a certificate into `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` truststore on my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
VOLUME /tmp
RUN keytool -import -alias vault -storepass changeit -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -noprompt -trustcacerts -file /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/certs/tls.crt
ADD wseccloudconfig-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```

As you can see I'm performing a command `keytool...` in order to insert the certificate to `cacerts`.

I'm deploying this image into my openshift/kubernetes cluster. Once I've connected to pod shell, I'm able to run this `keytool...` command rightly. So I mean, the command is well formed. There're no syntax problem or related issues...

So, I was excepting that the output of this command: `keytool -list -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` appears my certificate, but it doesn't appear.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Also I've tried writing this in `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD ["keytool", "-import", "-alias", "vault", "-storepass", "changeit", "-keystore", "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts", "-noprompt", "-trustcacerts", "-file", "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/certs/tls.crt"]
```

Comment: Maybe you should copy the file `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/certs/tls.crt` into the container before running the keytool command.

Comment: It's not possible. This file (`tls.crt`) is provided when the volume is mounted. It's not available at build time. Also I've tried with `CMD`. See post edition.

Comment: why don't cert be jks format? @user10063942

Comment: If it's not available at build time, the keytool import cannot work. Modify your entry point so that it's a script which first imports the certificate then runs your jar.

Comment: I think the solution is to add a `CMD` instead of changing `ENTRYPOINT`

Comment: Any fixed? I have a same issue

Answer (score 0):

Just like someone already stated in the comment - if you want to use the crt file that gets mounted at deployment, you have to add the keytool command to the deployment.

The crt you are trying to access when building the container does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add ca-certificates to your java keystore and supply them when the app is deployed, you should add the keytool command to your containers entrypoint script so it is performed when the certificate is available to your container.

entrypoint script:

```
#!/bin/sh

keytool -import \
-alias vault \
-storepass changeit \
-keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts \
-noprompt \
-trustcacerts \
-file /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/certs/tls.crt

java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim

ADD wseccloudconfig-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'

RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/wseccloudconfig && chmod -R 755 /var/lib/wseccloudconfig

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /var/lib/wseccloudconfig/

ENTRYPOINT ["/var/lib/wseccloudconfig/entrypoint.sh"]
```

not sure if I got the details right, but I hope you get the idea.

quick side note: jdk8 is kinda old at this point and if you are not bound to it for some reason, you should update to a newer jdk version. if you do that, be aware that the keytool command can change amongst different jdk versions.